# Passing a bundle in a message

Tags: android

So Im following the tutorial here: http://www.marioalmeida.eu/2014/02/21/how-to-do-android-ipc-using-messenger-to-a-remote-service/#comment-366

At the section just above Remote Service Manifest it talks about the service replying to activity by passing a bundle into a message using this code

```
Messenger mess = msg.replyTo; //retrieves messenger from the message
Message m = new Message();                  //create the message to send back to the client
Bundle b = new Bundle();                    //Just to show how to send other objects with it
b.putString(“messengerName”, “messenger1″); //this could be any parceable object
m.setData(b);                               //adds the bundle to the message
mess.send(m);                               //sends message
```

Im not sure how this works. Im looking at the android handler. It seems to differentiate the messages based on the what value. But If I follow the above then there is no what value (that I can see). All that is sent is the bundle. So what is in the what value for a message where it sends a bundle? If its empty how do i differentiate between messages sent with a bundle and ones sent using obtain?

Comment: are you just concerned with *what* vale of message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I follow the above then there is no what value (that I can see).

The message *WHAT* type has been set here :

```
 Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MSG_REGISTER, 0, 0);
```

Please check this method :

```
public static Message obtain (Handler h, int what, int arg1, int arg2)


Parameters
h       The target value to set.
what    The what value to set.
arg1    The arg1 value to set.
arg2    The arg2 value to set.
Returns
A Message object from the global pool.
```

Comment: Ahhhh okay. cool. cheers. This was wrecking my head. I thought they were two separate methods of sending messages but its the same message with different values, right?

Comment: Yes...  the value of MSG_REGISTER  will be set in all cases.